# String doesnt convert to int

Tags: java, android, string, int

I'm trying to get the text of an edittext and convert it to int but I'm facing this error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5
```

the code is very simple:

```
  temp=String.valueOf(editm.getText());

                minput = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                Toast.makeText(this, minput, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

temp is a string variable and minput is int type.
also I've tried .tostring() & Integer.valueof()

Comment: is your text in input is a number value ?

Comment: What is the type of `temp`?

Comment: Include the code that you are using to initialize editm (the EditText reference)

Comment: @MoHammaDReZaDehGhani u mean the input type of edittext?

Comment: @Jens as mentioned its string

Comment: Highly likely that the actual issue is with one of your findViewById calls

Comment: @SarwarErfan         editm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextm);
i don't think its the source of the issue, since I can use the string of it in Toast but can't convert it to int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to convert something to an int and then try to call `Toast.makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)`. If the second argument is an int, it is expected to be a resource id.

The question is whether you want it to be converted to an int at all. Right now, you're using its value only to show it on a toast message, which in turn expects a string to be passed.

```
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(minput), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This would Fix it :

```
    temp=editm.getText().toString().trim();
    minput = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    Toast.makeText(this, minput, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**UPDATE :**

It can issue for your toast : (try convert int to string in yout toast message)

```
Toast.makeText(this, minput.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: There is no datatype `Int` in java

Comment: was a misstake i fix it

Comment: @AmirRahmamzadeh kho findViewById kardi edittext ro ?

Comment: @MoHammaDReZaDehGhani are , hata khode stringesh ro mitonam to Toast mostaghim estefade konam v neshon mide , faghat int nemishe

Comment: @AmirRahmamzadeh fek konm toast faghat string migire

Comment: javab mano taeed bzan baw update kardam mnm hamino goftm mrc
@AmirRahmamzadeh